# Python and matplotlib - to many dates in x axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe which reports lists how many times this was called. I have summarized it per report and per date. now when I plot the whole thing with matplotlib, I always have way too many dates that are displayed.

Example of a record (report name, date, count):

```
8  ADOSperrenVK.avx"  2023-04-17   7278 
9  ADOSperrenVK.avx"  2023-04-18   4591
```

my code (the import from the data is not in the code):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

# Datum konvertieren
df['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TimeStamp'])

# Nur das Datum extrahieren
df['Date'] = df['TimeStamp'].dt.date

# Gruppieren nach Report und Datum und zählen
df_grouped = df.groupby([df['Report'], df['Date']]).size().reset_index(name='count')

# Top 10 Berichte auswählen
top_10_reports = df_grouped.groupby('Report').sum().nlargest(10, 'count').index.values
df_top_10 = df_grouped[df_grouped['Report'].isin(top_10_reports)]
unique_reports = df_top_10['Report'].unique().tolist()

# Schleife über die Berichte und Erstellung der Plots
for report in unique_reports:
    # DataFrame für den aktuellen Bericht erstellen
    df_report = df_top_10[df_top_10['Report'] == report]

    # Plot erstellen
    x = pd.to_datetime(df_report['Date'])
    y = df_report['count']
    plt.bar(x, y)
    plt.title(report)  # Titel für den Plot setzen
    plt.xlabel('Date')  # x-Achsenbeschriftung setzen
    plt.ylabel('Count')  # y-Achsenbeschriftung setzen
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)  # X-Achsenbeschriftungen um 45 Grad drehen
    plt.show()  # Plot anzeigen
```

The result is this

[image]

What do I need to do, that the I have only 2 entries (2023-04-17 and 2023-04-18 in the example) on the x axis?

Comment: What two labels are you looking to have on the x-axis?

Comment: i want the date on the x axis - 2023-04-17 and 2023-04-18

Comment: Replace `x = pd.to_datetime(df_report['Date'])` with `x = df_report['Date']` else matplotlib will use a DateLocator.

Comment: doesnt change the result. still have 7 entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Pandas` to plot the bar chart else `Matplotlib` try to infer the xlabel type with `AutoLocator`:

```
for report in unique_reports:
    # DataFrame für den aktuellen Bericht erstellen
    df_report = df_top_10[df_top_10['Report'] == report]

    # Plot erstellen
    ax = df_report.plot.bar(x='Date', y='count', title=report, rot=45)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()  # Plot anzeigen
```

Output

[image]

**Tips**

Use `groupby` instead of `unique`

```
# unique_reports = df_top_10['Report'].unique().tolist()

# for report in unique_reports:
#     # DataFrame für den aktuellen Bericht erstellen
#     df_report = df_top_10[df_top_10['Report'] == report]

for report, df_report in df_top_10.groupby('Report'):
    ...
```